# Extracting the tuples from a list of tuples of tuples wherein the tuple contains a string

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have got a List of tuples of tuples like below:

```
X= [(("a","b","c"),10),(("c","d","e"),20),(("f","e","g"),25)]
```

and I am trying to extract the tuples wherein "c" is present.

So the output should be

```
[((("a","b","c"),10),(("c","d","e"),20)]
```

I am trying to execute it in python.
 I tried this

```
[item for item in X if "c" in item]
```

However, it's not working.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
X= [(("a","b","c"),10),(("c","d","e"),20),(("f","e","g"),25)]
print([item for item in X if "c" in item[0]])
```

The o/p will be like :

```
[(('a', 'b', 'c'), 10), (('c', 'd', 'e'), 20)]
```